# making multiply keypress event shorter vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox, keypress

I have a lot of textboxes on my form (around 70). I want them to accept only HEX value. I have to write KeyPress event for each of the textboxes manually, and it is little bit frustrating. Is it possible to make this shorter?

```
 Private Sub TextBox66_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox66.KeyPress
        If Not "1234567890ABCDEF".Contains(Char.ToUpper(e.KeyChar)) AndAlso e.KeyChar <> vbBack Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub TextBox65_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox65.KeyPress
        If Not "1234567890ABCDEF".Contains(Char.ToUpper(e.KeyChar)) AndAlso e.KeyChar <> vbBack Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub TextBox64_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox64.KeyPress
        If Not "1234567890ABCDEF".Contains(Char.ToUpper(e.KeyChar)) AndAlso e.KeyChar <> vbBack Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub TextBox63_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox63.KeyPress
        If Not "1234567890ABCDEF".Contains(Char.ToUpper(e.KeyChar)) AndAlso e.KeyChar <> vbBack Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub TextBox62_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox62.KeyPress
        If Not "1234567890ABCDEF".Contains(Char.ToUpper(e.KeyChar)) AndAlso e.KeyChar <> vbBack Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub TextBox61_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox61.KeyPress
        If Not "1234567890ABCDEF".Contains(Char.ToUpper(e.KeyChar)) AndAlso e.KeyChar <> vbBack Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub TextBox52_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox52.KeyPress
        If Not "12345678".Contains(Char.ToUpper(e.KeyChar)) AndAlso e.KeyChar <> vbBack Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub TextBox60_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox60.KeyPress
        If Not "1234567890ABCDEF".Contains(Char.ToUpper(e.KeyChar)) AndAlso e.KeyChar <> vbBack Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub TextBox59_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox59.KeyPress
        If Not "1234567890ABCDEF".Contains(Char.ToUpper(e.KeyChar)) AndAlso e.KeyChar <> vbBack Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Create the eventhandler once from the form load event. This way you do not create redundant code.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each textbox As TextBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)
        If textbox.Name.StartsWith('TextHex') Then
           AddHandler textbox.KeyPress, AddressOf OnTextBoxKeyPress
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This is called for every keypress on your textbox

```
Private Sub OnTextBoxKeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs)
    If Not "1234567890ABCDEF".Contains(Char.ToUpper(e.KeyChar)) AndAlso e.KeyChar <> vbBack Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Finally, do a cleanup by removing the eventhandlers we defined during form load.

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    For Each textbox As TextBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)
        If textbox.Name.StartsWith('TextHex') Then
           RemoveHandler textbox.KeyPress, AddressOf OnTextBoxKeyPress
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

If your textboxes are inside another control (groupbox, panel), then you should change the scope used in the for loop from Me.Controls to (name of groupbox/panel).Controls

Comment: I would upvote your answer if you were to provide an explanation of your code (not just *what* you are doing, but *why*).

Comment: Thanks, but if i have few textboxes which should accept only numeric values? with your code as i got it, it will make all textboxes accept only hex values

Comment: Then you can name your textboxes in such a way like TextHex1, TextHex2 and so on. Then in the loop that creates the event handlers add a test whether the textbox's name starts with 'TextHex'. If it does, then create the handler. Don't if it doesn't. And name your non-hex textboxes in another way that they do not start with 'TextHex'.

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 3):

You can also list as many TextBoxes as you like after the "Handles" keyword; just separate them by commas like this:

```
Private Sub TextBox_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox52.KeyPress, TextBox59.KeyPress, TextBox60.KeyPress, TextBox61.KeyPress, TextBox62.KeyPress, TextBox63.KeyPress, TextBox64.KeyPress, TextBox65.KeyPress,TextBox66.KeyPress
    If Not "1234567890ABCDEF".Contains(Char.ToUpper(e.KeyChar)) AndAlso e.KeyChar <> vbBack Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

If you ever need the source Textbox, cast the "sender" parameter to a local variable of type TextBox:

```
Private Sub TextBox_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox52.KeyPress, TextBox59.KeyPress, TextBox60.KeyPress, TextBox61.KeyPress, TextBox62.KeyPress, TextBox63.KeyPress, TextBox64.KeyPress, TextBox65.KeyPress,TextBox66.KeyPress
    Dim tb As TextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
    If Not "1234567890ABCDEF".Contains(Char.ToUpper(e.KeyChar)) AndAlso e.KeyChar <> vbBack Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```